# Path of a file in an internal directory

Tags: android, file, directory

I have a file gpac.xlsx in the internal storage of my phone. I want to get its path. In android, it's confusing. Which one of these is the correct path?

- /data/sdcard0/gpac.xlsx
- /data/emulated/0/gpac.xlsx

Or  some other besides these?

Comment: No one of those is an existing or possible path. Further you did not tell us what you consider to be 'internal storage'. Further you did not tell how your file landed there.

Comment: I put that file there. InputStream is =  new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/gpac.xlsx"); it's giving the filenotfoundexception.  I'm considering the storage where the folders like DCIM,android,Movies,etc are, as the interenal storage.

Comment: No. Those are all subdirectories of /storage/emulated/0. And you get that path with getExternalStorageDirectory(). And the directory is called Android. Not android. And you did not tell how your file landed on the device.

Comment: The programs shows that the folder in which my file is present exists but as i add the file name and format it says that it doesn't exist.

Comment: I put that file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a file gpac.xlsx in the internal storage of my phone.

Based on your sample paths, your file is in what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> I want to get its path.

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "gpac.xlsx");
```

> Which one of these is the correct path?

It could be either of those or something else. Use the Java snippet shown above to derive the proper path at runtime for the particular device that your code happens to be running on.

Comment: It works with new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "gpac.xlsx"); But with new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "gpac.xlsx"); it gives FileNotFoundException

Comment: @MashhoodIjaz: Perhaps you do not have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission or did not request it at runtime.

Comment: That too was an issue but I observed that I had to put try catch around it but it wasn't giving any exception (code in try block ran successfully)